# How to create password less FTP connection?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ftp

I want to establish a password less FTP connection to a location but couldn't find anything related to this. I can establish a connection if I pass my credentials but I want it to be password less.Can anyone help me solving this problem?

I am using the following code to establish connection with password:
**ftp example.app.xyz.com** (executed in linux)
Then it prompts me for my credentials

Comment: Show minimal reproduction example how you are establishing the FTP connection with credentials.

Comment: I have updated the question with the details you have asked for.

Comment: AFAIK ftp doesn't allow for password less connections, even in anonymous mode you need to enter a password (even if it's a dummy one). You might consider something like scp or if you are old fashioned even rcp.

Comment: I have tried using scp but it doesn't work for me probably because of the security concerns at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If `ftp` prompts you for a password, it means that the server requires a password.

If you believe the server allows anonymous connection, it will accept anything for the password. So just press Enter.

Comment: The server definitely requires my credentials and I have the access to the server too. But I have to automate the process and hence I want to make it password less because I don't want to hard code my credentials in the script.

Comment: I'm lost. So are you asking how to configure the server to allow an anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to set up a password less connection using .netrc file and I am successful in doing that. But I have read that it's not a secure way of doing it. So, if anyone has any other way of doing it then that would be really helpful.